# How can I use Math.pow() to solve for compounding interest?

Tags: javascript, math, exponent

I am trying to calculate compounding interest with javascript. I believe I have all of the values I need, and I also have the formula. I'm struggling with how to translate the `^` part of the formula to `Math.pow()`. It will be painfully obvious that I do not know how to use it correctly below...

Here is the formula:

```
A = P(1 + r/n)^nt

n = 365 – assuming daily compounding
P = Principal
r = interest rate
t = years
A = accrued amount: principal + interest
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
totalInterest = (principal) * (1 + loanInterestRate / 365)(Math.pow(daysOfInterest, yearsOfInterest));
```

As an example, I have set prime as `3.25%`, and a payment due date of `12/30/2016`. Using values it looks like this:

```
(50000) * (1 + 0.0325 / 386) Math.pow(386, 1);

// 386 is the number of days from today till 12/30/2016. 
// 1 is: 1 year from today till 12/30/2016
```

Clearly that won't work. I am not sure how to implement the Math correctly, any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Thank you again for the answers. It was exactly the push I needed - clearly obvious I can't math.

I wanted to update this with my full answer as well...

```
totalInterest = Math.round(((principal) * Math.pow(1 + loanInterestRate / 365, daysOfInterest * 1)) - principal);
loanNetCost = (principal) + (loanTotalInterest);

alert('You will owe this much money: + loanNetCost');
```

Comment: The first argument to `Math.pow()` is the number to the left of `^` in your formula, and the second argument is the number on the right.

Comment: note that JS doesn't understand algebra. `(foo)(bar)` is a syntax error or at least a wrong way to try and call a function. it'd have to be `(foo) * (bar)`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I very much appreciate the help! I I checked the answer only because It shows the formula. If anyone comes across this thread they can see the excellent examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = P(1 + r/n)^nt

n = 365 – assuming daily compounding
P = Principal
r = interest rate
t = years
A = accrued amount: principal + interest
```

goes to

```
A = P * Math.pow(1 + r/n, nt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change it to:

```
(50000) * Math.pow(1 + 0.0325 / 386, 386 * 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.pow(daysOfInterest, yearsOfInterest)
```

means `n^t` so `Math.pow(386, 1)` means 386 to the power of 1.

You need all of the expression `(1 + r/n)` to be raised to the power of nt.

Giving

```
(50000) * Math.pow(1 + 0.0325 / 386, 386 * 1)
```